# In which version of C# was the ternary operator introduced?

Tags: c#, ternary

I have searched the most obvious sources but can't find the ternary operator listed as being introduced in a specific version. (I need to know this information for a historical reference).

Comment: It was always there, since 1.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was taught the ternary operator back when we were doing C in school, so I suspect it was never versioned into C#, but rather carried over from the existing language spec. [Citation needed]

Comment: @Flater Yes, the conditional operator was brought in from C.

Comment: I had wondered if that was the case. Can anyone point me to a reference showing that it was there in 1.0?

Comment: Wouldn't that be Delphi not C (to be pedantic). [Anders Hejlsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) based C# off Delphi (whom he was the chief architect). Now Deplhi was based on C (hence the pedantry) .

Comment: @Liam: It is my understanding that the _upgrade_ to C# (from C++, presumably?) was Delphi-inspired, not C# itself from the ground up.

Comment: I wonder what "historical reference" means? Are you writing a book or what is in your mind?

Comment: @Sinatr I am writing a paper on a specific aspect of computing history. This point is tangential to the main topic, but in a formal paper you can't make throwaway comments, you have to reference everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was introduced at the beginning, in C# 1.

If you want an authoritative source, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions) has links to the specifications. The [ECMA Spec](http://web.archive.org/web/20160306204059/http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/ECMA-334,%202nd%20edition,%20December%202002.pdf) for C# 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 says:

> ### 14.12 Conditional operator
>
> The `?:` operator is called the conditional operator. It is at times also called the ternary operator.
>
> ```
> conditional-expression:
>     conditional-or-expression
>     conditional-or-expression   ?   expression   :   expression
> ```

... and so on.

Comment: [Here's the _very first_ edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_1st_edition_december_2001.pdf).